# Intersection between a plane and a surface in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, plane-curves

I want to find the general expression for the intersection line of the following surfaces given in polar coordinates:
$$
z=f(r,\theta)
$$
$$
\theta=\pi/4
$$
where $f(r,\theta)$ is any real function in 3D cylindrical coordinates and the second surface is a vertical plane. Since the second plane equation is parallel to the $z$ axis, it doesn't have the $z$ term explicitly, but the intersection is assumed to occur. My question is on how can I express the intersection line for the general case of the first surface equation? Is it possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Presumably one of your $A$s is meant to be $B$. The line is $y=\frac AB x$? This fixes $\theta=\theta_0$ with $\tan\theta_0 = A/B$. Can you finish?

Comment: Actually is $A$ indeed (which now seeing looks unnecessary to write). The plane given in the second equation is given by $x=y$ in the cartesian coordinate system. I want to write the intersection of this plane with the surface $z=f(r,\theta)$.

Comment: Well, follow the rest of my comment, then, with $A=B$. :)

Comment: Thank you @TedShifrin, so the plane equation will be obviously $\theta=\pi/4$, but I still can't see how can I express the line given by this intersection. I'll edit the question adjusting the plane equation.

Comment: It's just $z=f(r,\pi/4)$, of course!!

Comment: I was thinking that I had something else haha thank you again @TedShifrin :)